# Display spinner on lightning:input type="search" field

Tags: lightninginput

At the moment I have spinner next to my search field, but it's wonky.

What is preferred way to display spinners for search fields?

Current solutions is...

[image: screenshot]

Essentially I want something similar that's done in some buttons that Salesforce use themselves:

```
        <lightning:button>
            hey
            <lightning:spinner/>
        </lightning:button>
```

[image: button overlay example]

Comment: What does your actual code look like? A proof of concept would help a long ways in fixing the issue.

Comment: Well was hoping to get some code out as an answer. Don't wanna fix existing issue, I wanna see if there's official way to overlay spinner over input field. I've seen buttons with spinners inside, but can't find that code anymore...

Comment: Found example with button, same idea - put spinner in input element body doesn't work.

Comment: Try wrapping lightning button inside a div with class 'slds-is-relative'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link might help you.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleInputSearchWithSpinner

Type something and then press enter, you will see the loading spinner there.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I needed!